# Smartface Repeatbox selectedItem is hiding

Tags: smartface.io

I added Repeatbox in the page. I getting json data. I set the useActiveItem as true. When I clicked the data, selectedItem is hiding. So, label is hiding. I want just give selected effect to row. How can I do this. My codes as follows.

```js
//Data Source
var myDataSource = [{
        row : "First Row"
    }, {
        row : "Second Row"
    }, {
        row : "Third Row"
    }
];


//label element to be included
var lbl = new SMF.UI.Label({
        top : "0%",
        left : "0%",
        width : "100%",
        height : "100%",
        fillColor : "#FFFFFF",
        textAlignment : SMF.UI.TextAlignment.center,
        touchEnabled:false
    });
    
//repeatbox list
var repeatBox1 = new SMF.UI.RepeatBox({
        width : "100%",
        height : "80%",
        left : "0%",
        top : "0%",
        showScrollbar : true
    });
    
repeatBox1.dataSource = myDataSource;
repeatBox1.onRowRender = function (e) {
    this.controls[0].text = myDataSource[e.rowIndex].row;
};

repeatBox1.onSelectedItem = function (e) {
    alert("Selected " + (e.rowIndex + 1) + ". row");
};

repeatBox1.onLongTouch = function (e) {
        alert("first row is deleted...");
};

repeatBox1.itemTemplate.height = Device.screenHeight / 7;
repeatBox1.itemTemplate.imageFillType = SMF.UI.ImageFillType.stretch;
repeatBox1.itemTemplate.add(lbl);


repeatBox1.useActiveItem=true;


Pages.Page4.add(repeatBox1);
```

Pages.Page4.add(repeatBox1);

Answer (score 0):

You have to style each type of element in the Repeatbox (inactive, active, header, etc). To do that, go to design view and select the repeatbox, then you'll see a drop down menu that you can choose the different types of elements. Click "Active Item" and you'll notice that the row style is default again. Now style the row how you want the active style to be. And that's it. :)

Comment: What, exactly, is not working? Because you don't need any code to do this. Just click the drop down, choose active, style the row, fill with data and that's it. Just make sure that "Use Active Item" is checked in the RepeatBox properties.